# Finding polynomial value at a point given values at $n+1$ other points

Tags: polynomials, lagrange-interpolation

> Let $F_n$ be the $n$-th Fibonacci number ($F_1$ = $F_2$ = $1$ and $F_{n+1}$ = $F_n$ + $F_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 2$). Let $P_n(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $P_n(k)$ = $F_k$ for $k = n+2, n+3,\dots,2n+2$. Prove that $P(2n+3)$ = $F_{2n+3} -1$.

---

I have attempted it through straightforward application of Lagrange interpolation method. I have arrived at a crazy summation. I have no idea if any of what I have done is right. If you could provide some details for the solution that would also help me realise if I'm dabbling out of my depth here and should start with simpler lessons.

Comment: Well, I suggest writing out $P_n(x)$ explicitly for small $n$.  Perhaps there is a simple pattern which could be proven inductively.

Comment: Could you provide your work? I have a different idea (that does not involve lagrange interpolation), but I think it would only be possible for people to point out any mistakes and help you if you provided your attempt.